# How do I write a JS function to do something and then return once that process is done?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm adding some functionality to an existing function.  I need to insert an additional step in the middle of the current routine.  I know how to go to the 2nd function but I don't know what to do to return to the main function once the 2nd routine completes.

```
function step1(){
    perform ajax call to see if student is assigned to a project
    step1_subfunction()
    //  wait here until step1_subfunction is done
    do some more stuff with response from user
}

function step1_subfunction(){
    prompt user via jQuery dialog, 'Add or move employee to the project?'
    //  return to step1 with answer returned from user and resume
}
```

I'd google this but I don't know if this "process" has a name.  Back in my days of COBOL, we called this gosub.

UPDATED:
*Step1* performs an ajax call to see if an employee has been assigned to a project. If the response.status = 'Assigned',  the user will be asked via a jQuery dialog box, "Do you want to copy or move the employee to this project?". The jQuery dialog box will be step1_subroutine. The answer will be passed back to the step1 function. The remaining part of step1 will simply be to place a value in a hidden text field of "copy" or "move".

Comment: as long as `step1_subfunction` doesn't execute any asynchronous code, that's exactly how it works

Comment: @scibuff like an ajax call by chance?

Comment: @dlackey: Yep.  It `step1_subfunction` contains an AJAX call, this won't work.

Comment: I've updated the details due to the asynchronous ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have will perform what you are describing, but may not make the data from the user available to function step1() without a return in function step1_subfunction(). Below I've modified your example code to demonstrate the passing of values back.

```
function step1(){
   //do some stuff
   var returnValFromFunction = step1_subfunction();
   //  wait here until step1_subfunction is done
   //  Now use returnValFromFunction, it contains the information from the user
   do some more stuff with response from user
}

function step1_subfunction(){
    prompt user for some information
   //  return to step1 with information returned from user and resume
   return userResponse;
}
```

Comment: I read up on the use of "return" and this looks to be what I needed.  Thanks, @wave

Answer (score 0):

What you've written should work - javascript is single-threaded, so have you tried it?

Javascript doesn't have subroutines specifically, just create a function that returns and ignore the result, as you have done. When the second routine completes, the scope and execution will continue in the first function.

Comment: I wrote out the skeleton and it /appeared/ to be single-threaded but before I started tweaking this existing procedure, I wanted to confirm my logic was correct.

Answer (score 0):

just do nothing.

what you are trying to achieve is just a "function call"

so it will automatically return to it's caller "stack frame" once executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the ajax object synchronous - IE, no code will continue until it gets a response. It's the third parameter of open (true is asynchronous, false is synchronous).

```
xmlhttpobject.open('POST', 'url', false);
```

There are cases where a synchronous call is fine but it should always be avoided if possible.

The other alternative, which would likely require some logic changes in your code but would be better off in the long run, is to bind the onReadyStateChange event. This fires every time the state of the xmlHttpRequest object changes - you can check to see if the status is 200 and the readystate is 4 to make sure the request is done and completed successfully.

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) a better reference. Good luck.